# Adding 1 after every jump in game

Tags: javascript, easeljs

I have a game and I'm trying to implement a score count that adds plus after every jump to a platform. Right now it adds only one after first platform and I can't figure out how to do the counting. Any help appreciated. I am using easelJS.

Code for the function right now:

```
update : function(){
    /* UPDATE LOGIC */
    this.velocity.x += this.acceleration;
    this.x += this.velocity.x;      

    if(this.x < this.outside){
        this.isOutsideLeft = true;
                   for (var counter =1; counter === 1; counter++){
                    document.getElementById('count').innerHTML = counter;

                    console.log('count');
    }
                }


},
```

Comment: What you're saying is "set `counter` to 1 - now run this loop until `counter` is 1 and after every iteration (hint, there are but one) add `1` to `counter`). Instead you should keep a global variable named `counter` and use `.innerHTML = (++counter);` (delete the loop completely - it's useless).

Comment: what's the point of this: `for (var counter =1; counter === 1; counter++){`

Comment: @h2ooooooo will try. thansk